# Proper way to initialize settings for a Jersey restlet

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to find out what is the proper way to initialize a `static` settings object, which should be loaded once and re-used by the restlets? Should I create a servlet which auto-loads, or is there (I am almost sure) a better way to do this?

Let's say I have a `configuration.xml` and would like to have it loaded so my restlets could start using it's settings. What would be the proper and most efficient way to do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ServletFilter that you map to your REST URLs in web.xml:

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyServletFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Then you override the init method to do your init business:

```
public class MyServletFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        loadConguration();
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be entered every single time the resource it requested?!

Comment: no there will be only one filter instance on which init will invoked only once for the life of your web-app instance. Depending on your server init might be called on web-app deployment or on first web request matching the url-pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes sense. I assume this is better than having a Servlet running with `autoload`...?

Comment: The purpose of a Servlet is to serve web requests for a particular URL pattern, which in your case sounds already fulfilled by Jersey, so one of your own would be redundant. Servlet Filters were defined for this purpose. They also allow you to run code before and after and even try/catch all the REST calls across all your Jersey resources via the doFilter method